# executing az acr hangs and never finish

Tags: azure, docker, azure-cli, acr

**Describe the error**

Running `az acr` within GitHub actions never finishes

**To Reproduce**

Run command inside the [AZURE CLI container](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-azure-cli) within Github Runner

```
az acr repository show-manifests --verbose --debug --name ACR-NAME --repository REPO-NAME --debug
```

**Expected behavior**

Show manifests of a repository in an Azure Container Registry.

**Output i got**

```
DEBUG: urllib3.connectionpool: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): acrname.azurecr.io:443
```

Comment: You can refer to [Why does my program hang after urllib3 logs Starting new HTTPS connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24628866/why-does-my-program-hang-after-urllib3-logs-starting-new-https-connection), [The library gets stuck on "Starting new HTTPS connection.](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/issues/1535) and [DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): login.microsoftonline.com:443](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python/issues/172)

Comment: Did you check the links mentioned in the above comment? Did you get the solution or workaround?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, nothing really works, after more investigation, it seems to be a TLS handshake error, the ACR is dropping the connection : `curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection reset by peer`

Comment: Try this : [Connection reset by peer when when hitting Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57773604/connection-reset-by-peer-when-when-hitting-docker-container) and [SSL/TLS connection issue troubleshooting test tools](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-paas-blog/ssl-tls-connection-issue-troubleshooting-test-tools/ba-p/2240059)

Comment: update: it's a TLS handshake problem, ACR server and our client can't agree on any cipher suite, investigation in progress.

Comment: What was the problem here ? I am running into the same issue.